# Create a function with CSharpScript and execute it

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to define a function as a Script and then run it ?

I'm trying to achive something like that:

```
//defined in a namespace
public class Params{public string input { get; set; }}


string script = "string TryToUpper(string input){ return input.ToUpper(); }";
var v = CSharpScript.Create(script,  globalsType: typeof(Params) );

// what to do to execute TryToUpper and get "GIUSEPPE" back?
var val = v.RunAsync(???);
```

Comment: I am not sure this is possible with CSharpScript; what if you create an in-memory assembly (using Roslyn) with that function? Would that be an acceptable solution for your use case?

Comment: @CoolBots if that's easy to do yes :) My end-goal is to easily have some code snippets that my application can execute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do two things in that script: first, define the function, then actually run it and return it's result. Like this:

```
public class Params
{
    public string input;
}

Params globals = new Params();
globals.input = "some lowercase text";

string script = "string TryUpper(string str) { return str.ToUpper(); } return TryUpper(input);";

string result = await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<string>(script, globals: globals);
```

Comment: I do not really  understand why I have to call return TryUpper at the end, but it does what I want :) thanks!

Comment: Looks like the entire script is evaluated, and the result assigned to the string in the executing code. You can likely substitute the entire script with `string script = "input.ToUpper()";` with the same effect.

Comment: Almost. You still need to actually return someting. so, you could replace it with `string script = "return input.ToUpper();";`

Comment: @Avo, I just tried it - works without `return`, but not with it.